# Join another field after the "min" function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

- `Customers`: customer_name
- `Visits`:  visit_date, visitor_name

I need a list of all customers, the first `visit_date`, and the first `visitor_name`. I'm having trouble getting the the first `visitor_name`..

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    customer_name, MIN(visit_date)
FROM 
    Customers 
LEFT JOIN 
    Visits 
GROUP BY
    customer_name
```

That I can do, but I don't know how to add the `visitor_name`, when I'm adding it, I see all visits and not only the first one!

Using SQL Server.

Please help - thanks.

Comment: Sample data, desired results would help.  It is not clear how the tables are joined together -- hopefully not on "name", that seems quite prone to error.

Comment: FIRST_VALUE() is your friend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to generate unique sequence to get first visitor name :

```
select *
from (select c.customer_name, v.visit_date, v.visitor_name, 
             row_number() over (partition by c.customer_name order by v.visit_date) as seq
      from customers c left join  
           Visits v
           on . . . -- provide key to JOIN
      ) t
where seq = 1;
```